# PreparedStatement with CONTAINS query

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I have a query that will need to run 28 000 times in a row, so I thought using a preparedStatement probably is a clever idea.

Here is my query :

```
String requestWithFirstName = "SELECT SE.ELEMENT_ID, SE.LASTNAME||' '||SE.FIRSTNAME AS ELEMENT, (SCORE(1)+SCORE(2))/2 AS SCORE "
                        + "FROM BL_SUSPICIOUS_ELEMENT SE "
                        + "WHERE CONTAINS(SE.LASTNAME, 'fuzzy({' || ? || '},' || ? || ',' || ? || ', weight)' , 1)>0 "
                        + "AND CONTAINS(SE.FIRSTNAME,  'fuzzy({' || ? || '},' || ? || ',' || ? || ', weight)' , 2)>0 "
                        + (type > 0 ? "AND SE.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = ?" : "") 
                        + " ORDER BY SCORE DESC";
```

Everthings worked fine until we realized that the fuzzy methods doesn't perform well for splitted words like 'pikachu is my hero' and it is advised to created, in this case, 4 fuzzy search for 'pikachu' 'is' 'my' 'hero'. Not sure if this is true, but as I will run the query 28 000 times it's a good opportunity to see it in action.

So I tried to modify the query in this manner :

```
 "SELECT A.ELEMENT_ID, A.LASTNAME||' '||A.FIRSTNAME AS AKA, SCORE(1) AS SCORE "
        + "FROM BL_AKA A, BL_SUSPICIOUS_ELEMENT SE " 
        + "WHERE CONTAINS(A.LASTNAME, ?, 1)>0 " 
        + "AND SE.ELEMENT_ID = A.ELEMENT_ID "
        + (type > 0 ? "AND SE.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = ?": "") 
        + " ORDER BY SCORE DESC";
```

In this case, ? will be set to :

> 'fuzzy({Burnham},70,4,weight),fuzzy({Investors},70,4,weight),fuzzy({Trust},70,4,weight)'

The query seems fine, running on sql dev. However, with Java, I get the following error :

> ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
>   DRG-50900: text query parser error on line 1, column 30
>   DRG-50920: part of phrase not itself a phrase or equivalence
>   DRG-50900: text query parser error on line 1, column 30
>   DRG-50920: part of phrase not itself a phrase or equivalence

Any advice ? 
I wonder if this is the same situation as the in statement (impossible to create a select * from pokemon where monster in (?))

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a prepared statement in java, it will set the parameter according to the method you use. So

```
String s = "'fuzzy({Burnham},70,4,weight),fuzzy({Investors},70,4,weight),fuzzy({Trust},70,4,weight)'";
statement.setString(s);
```

will be escaped again and results in:

```
'''fuzzy({Burnham},70,4,weight),fuzzy({Investors},70,4,weight),fuzzy({Trust},70,4,weight)'''
```

Try to set the parameter without the quotes.

You can create an `IN (?)` statement. But you will have to add a questionmark for every parameter: `WHERE monster IN (?,?,?,?,?,?)`...

Comment: Thanks, that was actually my mistake. Works perfectly now !