# Java Prepared Statement with CONTAINS query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a search query which must search a column in a table using contains search. There is ctxsys.context type index on the column. While fetching data on the table using prepared statement, the search query is not able to process special characters like -,/,_ etc.

Here is my code -

```
String query = "select * from parties where contains (party_name ,'%' || ? || '%')>0";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, searchName);
```

The code works fine for text which doesn't have special characters.

When I run the below query in sqlDeveloper it runs fine .

```
select * from parties where contains(party_name,'c/o')>0;
```

Please suggest what changes should I make in the prepared statement to make it work for special characters too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this question on how to use contains in prepared statement.
[PreparedStatement with CONTAINS query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723601/preparedstatement-with-contains-query)

You have to use escape in your queries if the above didint work 
like

```
SELECT * FROM BIRDS WHERE SPECIES='Williamson's Sapsucker 
statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM BIRDS  WHERE SPECIES='Williamson/'s Sapsucker' {escape '/'}");
```

reference from  http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=8881

Comment: yeah..tried using that..but didn't understand how it can work for me

Comment: Thanks Rahul..I am trying this solution out but getting some issues..will try to make it work...as per the suggestions we should add the escape part at the end of the query ..I am probably missing something